# Adding tsconfig exclude causes "Cannot write file" errors? in VSCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

If I add this `exclude` block to my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
 "exclude": ["angular-package-format-workspace"]
```

The following errors appear in VSCode.  They disappear if I remove the `exclude` block (Also the exclude block has the desired affect - so just curious why VSCode is painting the errors):

```
SON schema for the TypeScript compiler's configuration file

Cannot write file '/home/ole/Github/slice/target/dist/index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.ts
Cannot write file '/home/ole/Github/slice/target/dist/index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.ts
Cannot write file '/home/ole/Github/slice/target/dist/index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.ts
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es2017"],                        /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "./target",                     /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "strictNullChecks": false,                /* Enable strict null checks. */
    "baseUrl": "./",                          /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    "paths": {
      "@fs/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@test/*": ["./test/*"]
    },                                            /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */   
    "plugins": [
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
    ],
    "rootDirs": ["./src/"],                   /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "experimentalDecorators": true           /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
  },
  "exclude": ["angular-package-format-workspace"]  
}
```

Comment: Try adding the block, saving, then restarting Visual Studio Code. I've had similar issues with files in use causing weird errors in Typescript

Comment: Yup - That did it - Thanks!

Comment: great! I posted my comment as an answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the block, saving, then restarting Visual Studio Code.

Visual Studio Code holds open files when it is running, and this can conflict with other programs trying to read/write to them.